# Primitive double equals to NaN

Tags: java

Can someone explain how does it possible that primitive `double` type equals to `NaN` after following computations. Can you tell me some cases when `double` could end up as `Nan`? Thanks!

```
double averagePrecisionExisting = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    averagePrecisionExisting += logicWhichReturnsPrimitiveDouble();

double meanAveragePrecisionExisting = averagePrecisionExisting / x.size();    
System.out.println("Mean average precision of existing algorithm  = " + meanAveragePrecisionExisting);
```

Output: `Mean average precision of existing algorithm  = NaN`

Comment: To rehash, you actually *did* get `NaN` output, but you are asking the audience to provide *some cases* when it could happen?

Comment: What is the type of `x`? That doesn't look like it's going to be valid code.

Comment: You're missing a `;` in line 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your loop is meant to use `x.size()`, then it's pretty simple - if `x.size()` is 0, you'll be computing 0/0, which is NaN.

Otherwise, it could be that `logicWhichReturnsPrimitiveDouble()` returns a `NaN` for whatever reason. It's not clear why you've emphasized the "primitive" part in various places in your post - a primitive `double` is just as capable of representing NaN as `Double`. Indeed, the type of `Double.NaN` is `double`...

Answer (score 2):

For example, these are `NaN`s:

- `0d /0d`
- `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY / Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
- `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY / Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`
- `Double.NaN + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Well, NaN is produced if a floating point operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to produce some undefined result (e.g. 0.0 / 0.0).

It seems that if your x is zero and x.size() returns zero you will do exactly that.